# spam email/account @qq.com

Tags: magento-1.9, email, customer-account, security

Please can you help me with a problem started 1 week ago? every day a customer with chinese name appear on the customer list and our server start to send spam email (fortunately we block automatically the output emails).

please can you help me to find the problem?

Comment: Alberto, it really bad. You need track those  IP and block from Server.  IN this case, my Suggestion to  use Cloudflare

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds similar to an issue we had recently. What we found to be happening was that the customer was using the Share Wishlist functionality as a spam service.

The customer would create an account, add an item to their wishlist, and then choose to share the Wishlist. As there wasn't any limit on the number of email addresses the customer could enter, they were pasting in thousands. The customer would then enter their spam message in the message field and then send these, essentially using our website as a spam bot.

Our solution was to remove the Share Wishlist functionality. If you wish to keep the Share Wishlist functionality you could add a limit to the number of email addresses the customer is permitted to share their Wishlist with.

Comment: Hi wr125, thanks for your help, we added the smtp extension and checked the log files, the bot sent a lot of wishlist emails, we solved the problem with a filter in php, now block all the sender with @qq.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use below module to Protector your wishlist from used by spammers

https://github.com/vnahalpara/magento-Wishlist-Share-Spam-Protector

This module provide

captcha and email queue limits.

Comment: Link doesn't work.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/realmagento/magento-wishlist-share-spam-protector/src/1c95e10ec4797f0b4af05def70108e9a89e19942/?at=copy-master

Answer (score 0):

We had that spam issue on 3-4 projects up to now. In order to prevent spammers to use our platform, we’ve extended basic wishlist functionality with following restrictions:

1. Customer cannot share wishlist unless at least one order is completed
2. Customer has daily limit of shared wishlist (can ask for more)
3. Google captcha

Turning off wishlist share functionality is an option too, especially if the client is not using it.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue on a site where a fake customer account would be created, a product added to the wishlist, then the wishlist would get shared to hundreds of email addresses per request.  We implemented the following to resolve:

1. Added captcha to the customer registration form
2. Added a captcha to the share wishlist form
3. Limited the share wishlist form to sending to one email address per submission